# Splitting column containing state and region names in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create two separate columns from the following column in a data frame.

```
0                         State_1
1                            Auburn
2                          Florence
3                      Jacksonville
4                        Livingston
5                        Montevallo
6                              Troy
7                        Tuscaloosa
8                          Tuskegee
9                            state_2
10                        Fairbanks
11                          state_3
12                        Flagstaff
13                            Tempe
14                           Tucson
15                         state_4
16                      Arkadelphia
17                           Conway
18                     Fayetteville
19                        Jonesboro
20                         Magnolia
21                       Monticello
22                     Russellville
23                           Searcy
```

I want the above df to look something like this:

```
0  state_1                 Auburn
2  state_1                 Florence
3  state_1                 Jacksonville
4  state_1                Livingston
5  state_1                Montevallo
6  state_1                Troy
7  state_1                Tuscaloosa
8  state_1                Tuskegee
 ...

16 state_4                   Arkadelphia
17 state_4                   Conway
18 state_4                   Fayetteville
19 state_4                   Jonesboro
20 state_4                   Magnolia
21 state_4                   Monticello
22 state_4                   Russellville
23 v                         Searcy
```

As you can see, I want to sort of reverse pivot the data. I looked up the documentation on pd.pivot, but couldn't make any headway. Here is a dictionary of states:

```
states = {'OH': 'Ohio', 'KY': 'Kentucky', 'AS': 'American Samoa', 'NV': 'Nevada', 'WY': 'Wyoming', 'NA': 'National', 'AL': 'Alabama', 'MD': 'Maryland', 'AK': 'Alaska', 'UT': 'Utah', 'OR': 'Oregon', 'MT': 'Montana', 'IL': 'Illinois', 'TN': 'Tennessee', 'DC': 'District of Columbia', 'VT': 'Vermont', 'ID': 'Idaho', 'AR': 'Arkansas', 'ME': 'Maine', 'WA': 'Washington', 'HI': 'Hawaii', 'WI': 'Wisconsin', 'MI': 'Michigan', 'IN': 'Indiana', 'NJ': 'New Jersey', 'AZ': 'Arizona', 'GU': 'Guam', 'MS': 'Mississippi', 'PR': 'Puerto Rico', 'NC': 'North Carolina', 'TX': 'Texas', 'SD': 'South Dakota', 'MP': 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'IA': 'Iowa', 'MO': 'Missouri', 'CT': 'Connecticut', 'WV': 'West Virginia', 'SC': 'South Carolina', 'LA': 'Louisiana', 'KS': 'Kansas', 'NY': 'New York', 'NE': 'Nebraska', 'OK': 'Oklahoma', 'FL': 'Florida', 'CA': 'California', 'CO': 'Colorado', 'PA': 'Pennsylvania', 'DE': 'Delaware', 'NM': 'New Mexico', 'RI': 'Rhode Island', 'MN': 'Minnesota', 'VI': 'Virgin Islands', 'NH': 'New Hampshire', 'MA': 'Massachusetts', 'GA': 'Georgia', 'ND': 'North Dakota', 'VA': 'Virginia'}
```

Here is a code I tried. Be warned, this is an embarrassingly bad attempt (pretty much a novice in Python here).

```
#create new column for states only
df['State'] = 0

#Duplicate above combined column
df['Column_duplicate'] = df['Column']

for i in range(len(df)):
    if (dfl['Column_duplicate'].iloc[i+1] == df['Column'].iloc[i]):
           dfl['State'].iloc[i] = dfl['Column'].iloc[i]
```

Comment: why are you comparing sequential rows?  are the keys in format literally "state_1", or is "state_n" supposed to be one of the two letter states?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Everything is in a single column. State names are followed by region names. I want to put regions in a new column with their corresponding state names.

Comment: .iloc[i+1] == .iloc[i] is comparing sequential rows right (in a column)?

Comment: I'm asking what is the purpose of comparing two `Series` to assign to reassign multiple State columns to values of 'Column'.  I'm trying to understand what your goal is, because I'm having trouble understanding how `state_1` relates to `states` dict, or more specifically how is the delimiter "state_1" supposed to be determined.  Is it literally "state_n" or is it an actual State like "Ohio", or "OH"?

Comment: Best if I just show you -take a look at the pic: https://imgur.com/a/ZLoLUtd

Comment: See if @n1colas's answer works for you.  That would be my first guess on what you are trying to do.  But you brought up the `states` dict, so I would wonder if .contains should be a `str in states` check  EDIT: oh, it looks like state_ is in the string for regions, so contains won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dfl = (pd.read_csv('university_towns.txt', sep="[|]|(|)", header=None).rename(columns={0:'datamain'}))
    
dfl = dfl['datamain'].str.split("(", n = 1, expand = True)
dfl = dfl.loc[:,[0]].rename(columns={0:'State'})
dfl['RegionName'] = dfl['State'].str.strip()
dfl['State'] = dfl['State'].str.replace(r"[.*\]","").str.strip()
dfl['RN1'] = dfl['RegionName'].str.contains(r"\[.*\]","")
    
    for i in range(len(dfl)):
        if dfl['RN1'].iloc[i] != True:
            dfl['State'].iloc[i] = np.NaN
            
    dfl = dfl.ffill(axis = 0)
    df1
```

Data from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_college_towns#College_towns_in_the_United_States

Please note this I'm sure is a rather arduous way of doing this. In summary: `ffill()` function is what I wanted to create the state column.

Comment: looks fine if it is producing your desired output.  although the looping and ffill seems like they are redundant?  You should upvote and thank n1colas's answer, and then accept your own answer as the solution, or accept his solution if you think it was sufficiently close enough to what you wanted.  probably mention how `ffill` was key to helping you accomplish your goal, so people looking for something similar can find it easily

Answer (score 1):

You can mask the rows containing `state_` using `where`, and then use `ffill()` to populate the new colum with those values. After that, remove all rows with `state_` on both columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", header=None)
print(df)

mark = df[0].where(df[0].str.contains("state_", case=False))
df[1] = mark.ffill()
df = df[df.iloc[:, 0] != df.iloc[:, 1]]

df.columns = ['State', 'StateNum']
df = df[df.columns[::-1]].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Output from **df**

```
   StateNum         State
0   State_1        Auburn
1   State_1      Florence
2   State_1  Jacksonville
3   State_1    Livingston
4   State_1    Montevallo
5   State_1          Troy
6   State_1    Tuscaloosa
7   State_1      Tuskegee
8   state_2     Fairbanks
9   state_3     Flagstaff
10  state_3         Tempe
11  state_3        Tucson
12  state_4   Arkadelphia
13  state_4        Conway
14  state_4  Fayetteville
15  state_4     Jonesboro
16  state_4      Magnolia
17  state_4    Monticello
18  state_4  Russellville
19  state_4         Searc
```

Comment: look at the picture in the comments on OP.  Looks like you're going to need a regex or something similar to exclude state_1_region etc

Comment: @user120242 thanks for pointing this out, I hadn't seen the comment.

Comment: Ok this exact thing doesn't work, but Nicholas did provide me with the main function, which helped get this done and that is ffill(). I'm writing out my full code below. Let me know if there is a more efficient way to do it.